# Earliest use of the term "artificial friend"

Tags: identification-request

In the Kazuo Ishiguro 2021 novel *Klara and the Sun* the main character is an "artificial friend", i.e., a construction intended to be a child's companion. The idea of a child's robot companion is not new; in fact, I believe I have run across the phrase "artificial friend" used in this sense in an earlier story, but I cannot recall which. Can anyone point to an earlier story using this phrase in that sense?

Comment: Is this limited to only English-language works?

Comment: No, but I am sure I read it in English, so it would have to have been translated into English.

Comment: Are you looking for the first instance of this phrase or some specific work that you remember reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a notable early example of the phrase being used in this sense:

> A certain robot, planning to go on a long and dangerous voyage, heard of a most useful device which its inventor called an electric friend. He would feel better, he thought, if he had a companion, even a companion that was only a machine, so he went to the inventor and asked to be shown an **artificial friend**.
>
> <sub>Stanisław Lem (1972). ‘[Automatthew’s Friend](https://archive.org/details/mortalengines0000lems_i9m4/page/78/mode/2up)’. In *Cyberiada*, 3rd edition. Cracow: Wydawnictwo Literackie. Translated by Michael Kandel (1977). *Mortal Engines*, p. 79. New York: Seabury.</sub>

Comment: I have read most of Lem's stuff so I am fairly sure this is where I ran across it in the past.